# Prevent CreateDesktop from being opened

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am calling CreateDesktop to create a virtual desktop for security against keyloggers. However, somebody can easily open the desktop using OpenDesktop. I specifically want to prevent somebody from creating a process within that desktop.

The last parameter of CreateDesktop points to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure. However, I’m not sure how to use it.

I heard that you can’t have a process-level protection, but only user level. Is there a way to create a new restricted user and then have the last parameter use the credentials of the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can control accesses of others to the desktop you created via [security descriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdesktopa).

If the value of [lpSecurityDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa379560(v=vs.85)) member is `NULL`, the object is assigned the default security descriptor associated with the access token of the calling process. By default, **the default `DACL` in the access token of a process allows access only to the user represented by the access token.** (This is not the same as granting access to everyone by assigning a `NULL` discretionary access control list (`DACL`). A `NULL` `DACL` permits all types of access to all users.)

If the default security descriptor doesn't meet your requirements you can create `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` like grant only read access to someone and grant all access to yourself.

More reference: [Creating a Security Descriptor for a New Object in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: But how would I limit access to only my process? Like for example, only allow the current process (mine) to access the desktop, while preventing any OTHER PROCESS, even under the same user, to access the desktop?

Comment: Nevermind, I should’ve looked more closely at your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @User12341921 A process has different privilege when running under different user security context. All processes running as your user token have same rights by default. Preventing processes can't be done via creating the desktop. And you are not willing to prevent all other processes to access the desktop because system processes will behave unexpected then.

Comment: @User12341921 "*Preventing somebody from creating a process within that desktop*" can be achieved by creating `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` as mentioned in my answer. Feel free let me know if you still have any concern about this issue.